# Issues with Custom session handler Class in php 7.3

Tags: php

I'm creating a custom session handler class with OpenSSL encryption methods.

**My problem** is when I call the openssl_encrypt() directly, it's working well & data encrypted, but when calling it from write() function which invoked automatically when assigning value to `$_SESSION['msg'] = 'This data should be encrypted';`, the data not encrypted.

I'm using PHP 7.3.

**My custom class code:**

```
<?php

define("SESSION_SAVE_PATH", __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp_sessions");

class AppSessionHandler extends SessionHandler{

    private $sessionName        = "MYSESS";
    private $sessionMaxLifeTime = 0;
    private $sessionSSL         = false;
    private $sessionHTTPOnly    = true;
    private $sessionPath        = "/";
    private $sessionDomain      = 'localhost'; // or leave empty if not work
    private $sessionSavePath    = SESSION_SAVE_PATH;

        private $sessionCipherMode  = 'aes-256-gcm';
        private $sessionCipherKey   = 'WYCRYPT0K3Y@20-20';
        private $ivlen              = 16;
        private $tags               = NULL; 


        public function __construct(){

        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
        ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');

        session_name($this->sessionName);
        session_save_path($this->sessionSavePath);

        session_set_cookie_params(
            $this->sessionMaxLifeTime,
            $this->sessionPath,
            $this->sessionDomain,
            $this->sessionSSL,
            $this->sessionHTTPOnly
        );
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        return openssl_decrypt(parent::read($id), $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey);
    }

    public function write($sid, $data){
        return parent::write($sid, $this->encrypt($data) );
    }

    public function encrypt($plainText){
        if ( in_array ( $this->sessionCipherMode, openssl_get_cipher_methods() ) ) {
            $ivlen          = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->sessionCipherMode);
            $iv             = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
            $key            = random_bytes(32);
            $cipherData     = openssl_encrypt($plainText,$this->sessionCipherMode,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv,$tags);
        }
        return $cipherData;
    }

    public function start(){
        // start session if no session start yet
        if( session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            session_start();
        }
    }
}
```

The below code works well, but without encryption

```
$session = new AppSessionHandler();
$session->start();
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'This data should be encrypted';`
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered your custom session handler to the session system. Use the [`session_set_save_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to register your session handler:

```
session_set_save_handler(new AppSessionHandler());
```

You must remove the `ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');` line since that is not what you want to do.